# Is it possible to use $_SERVER variables as a value in an HTML input?

Tags: php, html

I have a form on a site which submits to a MySQL database. What I'd like to do is collect information using hidden inputs in the form to submit information contained in PHP `$_SERVER` variables to the database. I've already tried to do so like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']">
```

I quickly realized why that didn't work. However, I don't know the correct way to submit information from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`,
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` and other variables into my database.

The main idea is to use these hidden inputs to submit info from the client like IP address and form submission time. Any idea what I need to do?

Comment: Why not use an obscure default and replace?

Comment: I do hope that field is enclosed in this statement or something similar: `echo '<input type="hidden" value="$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']">';`

Comment: why you use hidden file, you can directly insert $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] , in your insert function

Comment: Does the form submit to one of your `.php` files?

Comment: Good question from Phil. If it does you don't need to submit the values as you already have access to them in the script you submit them too...

Comment: @Capsule Ok, I get what you guys are saying. It makes more sense to use them inside my `.php` file. Was just curious if it was even possible, or practical, to use them within the HTML file.

Comment: You can't use PHP variables in an HTML file, they will just show up as plain text.

Comment: @Capsule of course I wouldn't be using them outside of `.php` tags. I just thought I could do something like: `value="<?php  echo $_SERVER['something'] ;?>"`.

Comment: You can, but again, if you submit to the same server, there's no point doing it in the form, just do it in the script logic that receives the submission.

Comment: @Capsule makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go through these steps instead of playing around at client end to get the `SERVER` details.

> $_SERVER is used to fetch all the detailed information about the
>   server as its a reserved variable in PHP and comes under the category
>   of SuperGlobals.

[$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is an array containing information such as headers, paths, and script locations.

> In your case when the form is being submitted to some *action(function)*
>   at the server end, from there you can get the details of server and
>   its host using **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']** and then pass it to your
>   database.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER` is Superglobals  variable why are you trying to sent one page to another page with hidden input or something like that .you can access it from any where in the script. 
see here for more detail.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

OR

if you want send by hidden input then need to echo out something like this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php  echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ;?>">
```